# animated progress bar with counter ie8 issue

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, jquery-animate, progress-bar

Hi I have an animated progress bar with percentage counter and it works great in all browsers except ie8. The issue is the bar animation reaches the end before the percentage counter has reached 100% meaning the counter is lagging behind where it should be.

Has anyone else ever experienced this issue with IE8?

Thanks

Comment: there are probably thousands of progress bars. Please show us yours or we can't do much. Also check `margins` and `padding`

Comment: apologies yeah here is a fiddle example - you will see it works perfectly but IE8 has the issue..... http://jsfiddle.net/Pg7gs/

Comment: apologies the above is slightly wrong the issue is that the bar rises with the counter to the desired stop point together. However the animation reaches the end point but the numbers are behind and are still counting to the end result but they should both finish at the same time if that makes sense? Also let me know if you need a proper url to test instead of the fiddle...thanks

Comment: try changing the animation speed from `3200` to `3350`.

Comment: i have tried that but it doesn't work - the animation is still out of sync. I don't want to increase the speed by too much either otherwise it will go out of sync with all of the other browsers. I have also tried linking to an ie8 only js file but this had a strange effect rising correctly but then lowering back down again